# Consecutive/Unbroken occurrences in time series

Tags: r, datetime

I'm working with a data table in R containing information quarterly information on the products being sold in grocery stores across the United States. In particular, there is a column for the date, a column for the store, and a column for the product. For example, here is a (very small) subset of the data:

```
Date           StoreID       ProductID
2000-03-31     10001         20001       
2000-03-31     10001         20002
2000-03-31     10002         20001
2000-06-30     10001         20001
```

For each product in each store, I want to find out for how many *consecutive* quarters the product has been sold in that store up until that date. For example, if we restrict to just looking at staplers that sold in a specific store, we would have:

```
Date           StoreID       ProductID
2000-03-31     10001         20001       
2000-06-30     10001         20001
2000-09-30     10001         20001
2000-12-31     10001         20001      
2001-06-30     10001         20001
2001-09-30     10001         20001
2001-12-31     10001         20001
```

Assuming that's all the data for that combination of StoreID and ProductID, I want to assign a new variable as:

```
Date           StoreID       ProductID     V
2000-03-31     10001         20001         1
2000-06-30     10001         20001         2
2000-09-30     10001         20001         3
2000-12-31     10001         20001         4
2001-06-30     10001         20001         1
2001-09-30     10001         20001         2
2001-12-31     10001         20001         3
2002-03-31     10001         20001         4
2002-06-30     10001         20001         5
2002-09-30     10001         20001         6
2002-12-31     10001         20001         7
2004-03-30     10001         20001         1
2004-06-31     10001         20001         2
```

Note that we roll over after Q4 2000 because the product was not sold during Q1 of 2001. Additionally, we roll over after Q4 2002 because the product was not sold during Q1 2003. The next time the product was sold was Q1 2004, which was assigned a 1.

The issue I am having, is that my actual dataset is quite large (on the order of 10 Million rows) so this needs to be done efficiently. The only techniques I've been able to come up with are dreadfully inefficient. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why V resets to 1 in line 5? Because time difference is too larger or because it's a new year? Also, please add more data (multiple stores and products) using `dput` function.

Comment: It resets because product 20001 was not sold in store 10001 for a quarter. Notice that the date skips.

Comment: Does my solution work or is there something I can improve in it?

Comment: @PoGibas I'm assessing it right now. It looks very promising!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom function that calculate difference between quarters.

```
# Load data.table
library(data.table)
# Set data as a data.table object
setDT(data)
# Set key as it might be big data
setkey(data, StoreID, ProductID)

consecutiveQuarters <- function(date, timeGap = 14) {
    # Calculate difference in dates 
    # And check if this difference is less than 14 weeks
    shifts <- cumsum(c(FALSE, abs(difftime(date[-length(date)], date[-1], units = "weeks")) > timeGap))
    # Generate vector from 1 to number of consecutive quarters
    ave(shifts, shifts, FUN = seq_along)
}

# Calculate consecutive months my storeID and productID
data[, V := consecutiveQuarters(Date), .(StoreID, ProductID)]
```

Comment: So this didn't quite work. For a given store suppose the same product is sold for 10 consecutive quarters (starting in Q1 of a given year for simplicity). Looking along the dates, instead of getting 1,2,3,4,5,6,...,10, this code gives me 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2. This is happening because the difference of the quarters when the year rolls over is -1. If we change the definition of "shifts" in the consecutiveQuarters function by taking the difference modulo 4, this fixes the problem, but adds a new one. The code would view Q1Y1 and Q2Y100 as sequential. Must we incorporate year somehow? Thoughts?

Comment: @Joe can you add to your question such example (ie sequential years that have to return 1:10). You can use function `dput()` for that

Comment: I added such an example (but only 1-7 instead of 1-10). I also added an example of the new problem that introducing modular arithmetic would cause.

Comment: @Joe I edited my answer. I changed it to use function `difftime`. With it we calculate difference in weeks (max allowed unit) and check if this difference is <= 14 weeks.

Comment: So it looks like that's working! That being said, the code is throwing a bunch of warning messages. The following 2 are being thrown 100s of times each.  First, it's throwing: "Warning message:
In unclass(time1) - unclass(time2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"                                 Additionally, it's throwing:"In `[.data.table`(data, , `:=`(V, consecutiveQuarters(date)),  ... :
  RHS 1 is length 11 (greater than the size (10) of group 27). The last 1 element(s) will be discarded."

Comment: @Joe Can you please check, I edited my answer to solve warning part

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @Joe Happy to help, let me know if there's some kind of improvement you need

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable which is 1 if the product is sold in a quarter and 0 if not.  Order the variable so it starts at the present and goes backward in time.

Compare the cumulative sum of such a variable to a sequence of identical length.  When sales drop to zero the cumulative sum will no longer equal the sequence.  Sum the number of times the cumulative sum equals the sequence and this will tell the number of consecutive quarters sales were positive.

```
data <- data.frame(
  quarter = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4),
  store = as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)),
  product = as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)),
  numsold = c(5, 6, 0, 1, 7, 3, 2, 14)
)


sortedData <- data[order(-data$quarter),]

storeValues <- c("1")
productValues <- c("1","2")

dataConsec <- data.frame(store = NULL, product = NULL, ConsecutiveSales = NULL)

for (storeValue in storeValues ){
  for(productValue in productValues){

    prodSoldinQuarter <- 
      as.numeric(sortedData[sortedData$store == storeValue &
                        sortedData$product == productValue,]$numsold > 0)

    dataConsec <- rbind(dataConsec,
                        data.frame(
                          store = storeValue,
                          product = productValue,
                          ConsecutiveSales = 
                            sum(as.numeric(cumsum(prodSoldinQuarter) == 
                                     seq(1,length(prodSoldinQuarter)) 
                                    ))
                          ))

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your question your really need your V column as quarter of year, not sum of product in each quarter. You can use something like that.

```
# to_quarters returns year's quarter of given date in character string
# base on reg exp    
to_quarters <- function(date_string) {
  month <- as.numeric(substr(date_string, 6, 7))
  as.integer((month - 1) / 3) + 1
}

# with tidyverse library
library(tidyverse)
# your data as tibble format of data frame
data_set_tibble <- as.tibble(YOUR_DATA)
# here you create your table 
data_set_tibble %>% mutate(V = to_quarters(Date) %>% as.integer())


# alterative with data.table library
library(data.table)
# your data as data.table format of data frame
data_set  <- as.data.table(YOUR_DATA)
# here you create your table 
data_set[,.(Date, StoreID, ProductID, V = to_quarters(Date))]
```

For tidyverse and data.table performance is a same, in my case for 5 000 000 rows works in 12 seconds

Comment: This is not what I need. I want the number of consecutive quarters a product has been sold in a store. Not the quarter of the year.